# How can I extract string's parts in R?

Tags: r, string, extract

I have the following phrase located in my df$just and I would like to return 1 if the word "PELAMOR" matches at least once and 0 otherwise:

"Contabilização conforme IN ccc .    IMPORTE PARA FECHAMENTO DE BALANCETE. Objeto........:PELAMOR  Subobjeto.....:PELAMOR DEUS E DEMAIS cfe IN 365/4.2.2.3.2."

```
What I have tried so far, but all I got is 0 instead of 1:
binario <- data.frame(just = df$just, 
                      PELAMOR = grepl("PELAMOR",tolower(df$just))*1)
```

Comment: Strange you are using `tolower` but your pattern `PELAMOR` is in caps. Consider this `grepl("PELAMOR",tolower(just),ignore.case=TRUE)*1`, with `just <-"Contabilização conforme IN ccc . IMPORTE PARA FECHAMENTO DE BALANCETE. Objeto........:PELAMOR Subobjeto.....:PELAMOR DEUS E DEMAIS cfe IN 365/4.2.2.3.2."`

Answer (score 1):

If we need a binary vector, coerce the logical from `grepl` to binary with `as.integer` or (`+`).  In the OP's code, the column is converted to lower case while the `pattern` is upper case resulting in mismatch and getting all zeros.  Instead, there is `ignore.case` argument, which is by default `FALSE`

```
as.integer(grepl("PELAMOR", df$just, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

---

With `stringr`, we can use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
+(str_detect(df$just, fixed("PELAMOR", ignore_case = TRUE)))
```